# Read a list within a list from csv java (see below)

Tags: java, csv

This is how my sample csv looks like. I have two rows. Each row is an array list but you can see that I have another list within the list of type Fruit. How do I go about reading this in java? Thank you.

2,3,4,<apple,red,round>,true

1,2,7,<banana,yellow,long>,false

Comment: How this `<apple,red,round>` looks in csv?

Comment: Depends on the Java object you want to read it into. Does it declares the second list as a List or you want to destructure it into the object itself?

Comment: Just the way I put it in the post @KunLun

Comment: Like this: `| 2 | 3 | 4 | <apple | red | round> | true |` or like this: `| 2 | 3 | 4 | <apple, red, round> | true |` ? And, can you show the code of what have you tried?

Comment: First one @KunLun but with commas instead of |

Comment: I have a class called Item and one of the fields is fruit list of type Fruit but currently I’m stuck on reading the csv file. I can read the csv file if <apple,red,round> isn’t there.

Comment: CSV does not support nested lists. That violates [the specification](https://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc4180). I suggest you inform the publisher of your data that they should be using a hierarchical data format such as XML, JSON, etc.

Answer (score 0):

If you can ***guarantee*** that the `<` and `>` symbols in your CSV file will ***only*** be used to mark the start and end of an embedded list, then you can use a CSV library such as [OpenCSV](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.opencsv/opencsv), with the following approach.

Imports:

```
import com.opencsv.CSVParser;
import com.opencsv.CSVParserBuilder;
```

Sample code:

```
String sampleRecord = "2,3,4,<apple,red,round>,true";
        
final CSVParser csvParser = new CSVParserBuilder()
                .withQuoteChar('<')
                .build();

String[] fields = csvParser.parseLine(sampleRecord.replace(">", "<"));

for (String field : fields) {
    System.out.println(field);
}
```

This prints the following output:

```
2
3
4
apple,red,round
true
```

Now you can take the data from `apple,red,round` and parse that again, to get each item in the list, as needed.

This approach works by replacing the closing `>` with `<`, and then by using `<` as the defined quote character: `withQuoteChar('<')`. This means that text inside `<` is treated as a single field.

But, just to repeat, ***this code will break*** if the assumption mentioned at the start is ever broken. So it depends on your input data.